# Database of .oxt dictionaries - contribution to global "official" .oxt dictonary of some language

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries, libre-office

Is there some database where one can download *up-to-date* versions of (`.oxt`) dictionaries and perhaps it being crowdsourced so anyone can contribute to it?

I keep adding words to my `dict-hr.oxt` dictionary when using TeXstudio and so I wonder how many had to add the same word to their local dictionaries.

Comment: Can you specify what OS you use? E.g. in Linux you can use system-wide Hunspell dictionaries.

Comment: I use both Linux (Mint) and Windows 7, I'll look into that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use the `oxt` files from libreoffice for use in texstudio. To contribute to these dictionaries, contact the coordinator of the language you want to contribute and offer your help.

A list of contact persons can be found at https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can set up TS to use Hunspell dictionaries in Spell Checking — Spell check — Spelling dictionary directories — `/usr/share/hunspell` (the path depends on your distro).

Here is a [GitHub repo for Croatian](https://github.com/krunose/hunspell-hr) Hunspell, updated 22 days ago.